# How to install QtMultimedia source?

Tags: qt, multimedia

I need QtMultimedia to compile an open-source project. But it wasn't installed with qt.

I've tried

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qtmultimedia5-dev
```

But it doesn't find such a package.

I've downloaded it from ubuntu site, but unable to compile - there're just *.install files in tar.gz.

How to get it?

Answer (score 2):

Enable the **Universe Repository** in Software and Updates.

Then update all the repositories,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then run the below command,

```
sudo apt-get build-dep qtmultimedia5-dev
```

It will surely find the `qtmultimedia5-dev` package.

Comment: No, it doesn't help. I've activated universe, but my muon package (and console too) manager still finds no qtmultimedia5

Comment: after enabling the universe repository,did you update it?

Comment: yes, I've updated

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install qtmultimedia5-dev
```

Comment: This one works. Thanks.